# Title of html inside php inside html

Tags: php, html, title, head

I'm kind of learning all by myself, and I'm using the W3 validator to check my code.
Now I got this document which loads:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
include("menu.php");
?>

<?php
if (is_file("$file.inc.php")) include ("$file.inc.php");
else include("homepage.inc.php");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

In the menu you chose for example 'Page A', which then loads as "pageA.inc.php" which contains:

```
<title>SUPERAWESOME TITLE of page A</title>
text text text
...
```

It works fine but I get this set of errors in the W3 validator which I don't know how to handle:

1. In the first set of code: end tag for "HEAD" which is not finished, doesn't contain "TITLE"
2. In the second set of code: document type does not allow element "TITLE" here

If I set a title in the first set of code, to solve the first problem, it always shows me that same title.
If I set the  tags in te second set of code I get more errors in the W3 validator saying that it doesn't allow it there.

How could I solve this issue?
Or shouldn't I care? It's working right now the way it should, I'm just bothered by the errors when validating.

Comment: That's right, yes, the `<title>` should go inside the `<head>`, not in the `<body>`. That's just how it is. The title is part of the information about the html file, not part of the content. So put the included title somewhere between the `<head>` and the `</head>`.

Comment: Any specific reason for using HTML4? Or ISO-8859 for that matter.

Comment: @Juhana and what is wrong with HTML 4? Or ISO-8859-1 for that matter.

Comment: @MrLister Nothing, but you'd think that if you're starting from zero you'd go straight to 5. But not using Unicode is just wrong unless there's an outside reason for that.

Comment: @Juhana OK, but you do realise that many of the browsers don't really do HTML5 yet? Take `<input type="number">` for instance; support for that is fragmentary at best.

Comment: @MrLister To my knowledge all browsers fall back to `type="text"` if they encounter a type they don't recognize. On the other hand using HTML4 doctype doesn't have any benefit even if you wouldn't use any HTML5-only features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing your title to the body of your html, and this is not valid. The title should be in the head, e.g:

```
<head>
    <!-- other head tags -->
    <title>Your Title</title>
</head>
```

You can do an include also in your head section:

```
if (is_file("$file.inc.php")) include ("$file.header.inc.php");
```

And in your inc file just output `<title>...</title>`. Then in the body section you can include another file with text output, then your html markup should be valid.

Comment: But the title should depend on which file is open inside.
If I set the tags in the second set of code I get more errors in the W3 validator saying that it doesn't allow it there.

Comment: For example create for each file 2 include files, one starting with `header.` and then do `if (is_file("$file.inc.php")) include ("$file.header.inc.php");`

Comment: Thanks, this worked!
One more question, is it worth it to make 10+ files just containing the titles of the pages, for something that gave errors only on W3; but worked anyways?

Comment: There are better ways to get the right title. For example you could store all values you need in an object, an a php file that creates your full html markup uses this values, but thats much more work

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this
You missing `end tag` for `meta` and you need to add `title` inside `head` based on the current page

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

   <?php
    include("title.php");
    ?>

    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    include("menu.php");
    ?>


    <?php
    if (is_file("$file.inc.php")) include ("$file.inc.php");
    else include("homepage.inc.php");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```